# Recursive ls with conditions

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ls, recursive

Why can't I use a command like this to find all the pdf files in a directory and subdirectories? How do I do it? (I'm using bash in ubuntu)

```
ls -R *.pdf
```

EDIT

How would I then go about deleting all these files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Why can't I use a command like this to find all the pdf files in a directory and subdirectories?

The wildcard `*.pdf` in your command is expanded by `bash` to all matching files in the current directory, *before* executing `ls`.

---

> How do I do it? (I'm using bash in ubuntu)

find is your answer.

```
find . -name \*.pdf
```

is recursive listing of pdf files. `-iname` is case insensitive match, so

```
find . -iname \*.pdf
```

lists all .pdf files, including for example `foo.PDF`

Also, you can use ls for limited number of subfolders, for example

```
ls *.pdf */*.pdf
```

to find all pdf files in subfolders (matches to bar/foo.pdf, not to bar/foo/asdf.pdf, and not to foo.PDF).

If you want to remove files found with find, you can use

```
find . -iname \*.pdf -delete
```

Comment: Just in case you want an output similar to the `ls -l` command, showing file size, ownership, date, etc., you can use `find` with the `-ls` option, e.g. `find . -name \*.pdf -ls`

Comment: then how would you list them by file size?

Answer (score 3):

Use find instead of ls

```
find . -name '*.pdf'
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, find is the answer.

Now to answer the other part.

- How would I then go about deleting all these files?

  find . -iname *.pdf -exec rm {} \;

Should do it.

Comment: You need to quote your glob to keep it from being prematurely expanded.